# Getdate() function shows different value

Tags: sql-server

When we are using

```
Select Getdate()
```

we get an output of:

```
'2017-08-21 09:31:50.660'
```

but the system time is

```
'2017-08-21 09:33'
```

Comment: GETDATE() checks the server that the instance of SQL is running on (which may not be your local machine and may not have the same time as your local machine).

Comment: Thank you very much, This is Very helpFul

Answer (score 1):

```
GETDATE()
```

Function provides server machine's current date time but not local machine.